Does it make sense to mature a yeast dough made from gluten-free flour?
Usually, when I make the dough for bread or pizza I let it mature in the fridge overnight.
I bought a gluten-free flour for a friend consisting of:

gluten-free wheat starch
cornstarch
dextrose
buckwheat flour
psyllium seed fiber
rice starch
thickener: guar

Given these ingredients, does it make sense to mature in the fridge or is it completely useless? Of course I add also a yeast for leavening.

Do you add any yeast to this?

@bob1 yes of course, I didn't specify in the question, my fault. I'm going to update it

Are you asking about maturing the flour or maturing the dough made from the flour?

@mkrieger1 sorry for my English, I'm asking about maturing the dough make from the flour, water and yeast

As you add yeast (and presumably activate it, mix into the ingredients with some liquid etc.), then yes, maturation of the dough in the fridge should work.
The purpose of maturation in the fridge is twofold -
First it allows you to make the dough beforehand and leave until the following day. This, of course, isn't absolutely necessary, you can rise on the spot, but this leads into second...
Second, the maturation results in a depth of flavour that you don't get with instant use of the dough. This is because the yeast is still fermenting, albeit slowly, in the fridge. This means that you get more time for secondary fermentations to occur. This results in secondary metabolites, beyond simple alcohols and carbon dioxide. The secondary metabolites are commonly things like esters and other "flavoured" compounds which add the depth of flavour to the dough that you don't get with a short/immediate fermentation.

From my point of view: no, it doesn't matter much. You can skip that step.
For me, the main purpose of "aging" dough is the different texture. It's a way of developing the gluten without kneading, which produces a very nice, pliant texture in the dough, lets you make hand-pulled pizza, and also gives you a better texture in the baked pizza. Since the gluten-free dough lacks gluten (duh), this is not happening in a gluten-free pizza at all.
The best you can expect in the texture department is that a good starch hydration is quite helpful for gluten-free flours. But that part should be achieved by a normal rise (1-2 hours at room temperatures), I don't think there will be much improvement by even longer standing times.
This doesn't invalidate bob1's point about the flavor changes from a long fermentation. But I would argue that these changes are too slight. They will be quite noticeable in a single-grain non-enriched bread loaf. But you're making a pizza, which is an explosion of flavors and fat hitting the taste buds at once. The subtle nuances of a slightly different yeast aroma simply go under for most pizza eaters.
And even for the people who mindfully chew on the crust for a minute, inhaling each detail, there is no automatic certainty that long-fermented will be better than short-fermented. Artisans praise the taste of long-fermented breads (and sometimes pizza crusts), because it's more complex and more difficult to achieve. But people's preferences are all over the place, and that's OK.
So, in conclusion: there will be some difference, but not really that much, and certainly not as important as for wheat pizza base. You're of course free to experiment and see if you find it worth the extra effort. But there is no requirement to always do it, and may go unnoticed even if you do.

When I make pizza or bread with long rise (overnight maturation in the fridge) I notice it's more "digestible". The different taste is a secondary "nice-to-have" feature for me. But I still knead the dough a lot.
